# Can't access the checkout/onepage/ in magento 1.5.0.1?

Tags: magento-1.5

Can anybody help with this , I have cloned a production  site to my local server for development and testing which seems to be working ok. I have created some new app/skin packages and applied and tested them.

But the checkout links are not working either from the cart or top-links or the mini sidebar cart , also the login link does not work.

The url's are

```
      https://127.0.0.1/silkyliving/index.php/checkout/onepage/

      https://127.0.0.1/silkyliving/index.php/customer/account/login/
```

I get "This webpage is not available
The connection to 127.0.0.1 was interrupted".message.

I've installed the default package and other packages to see if the fault lies in my package but it does it in any package.

So i think the fault is in the overal configuration/install.

I have also tested my local server with another install and that works ok so is not a server error.

To be honest i never checked the checkout functions when i cloned the production site so not sure where the fault is, the production site is working ok ?

Does anybody have any ideas ?

Thanks

Ledgemonkey

Comment: I have discovered the problem it was in >configuration >web - Use Secure URLs in Frontend was set to "yes" changed it to "no" and seems to be working ok now  ? thanks

Comment: Will post as anwser but can't do it for 7 hours !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the problem it was in >configuration >web - Use Secure URLs in Frontend was set to "yes" changed it to "no" and seems to be working ok now  ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

goto Magento root index.php

ini_set("memory_limit","512M");
// echo ini_get("memory_limit"); //for test

then all are solved.